# Special characters in tag get removed for comparison on save

Tags: tags

Is there a list of characters, that are not allowed / are allowed in Tags? Or are there some more complex rules?

I first ran into the issue, that some tags are ok with a `*`-prefix, like: `*BLA-BL-BLA` but others are not `*BLA-BL-BLA blah`.

But after doing more testing, i found out, that i can not add a tag like `+BLA-BL-BLA blah` after `*BLA-BL-BLA blah`. The other way round also does not work.

It seems like the special chars get removed before a comparison and then the string matches an existing tag...

Comment: Does it make sense to use non-alphanumerics in a tag? I could understand if you were asking for non-Roman characters, but it's particularly symbols you're having problems with? Still I'm surprised it doesn't just work: I suspect the tags get any punctuation stripped before being turned into a tag slug, and that's what's catching you out here.

Comment: After that "bug" was sent to me, i immediately advised against using certain "special characters" in such fields and started researching. Problem is: it is already done at several places and hopefully, the users of the system will agree to use a different prefix. Nonetheless i am curious over why that happens, since i did not find a good ressource providing help on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when you add a new term, WordPress will use [`term_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_exists/) to validate term  before add it to database.

1. `term_exists()` uses [`sanitize_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) which uses [`remove_accents()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_accents/) and [`sanitize_title_with_dashes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/) to sanitize term.
2. `remove_accents()` will converts all accent characters to ASCII characters and `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` will limits the output to alphanumeric characters, underscore (_) and dash (-), whitespaces will be converted to dashes, uppercase characters will be converted to lowercase characters.
3. WordPress also doesn't allow to create terms which have the same term slug at the same level of a taxonomy hierarchy.

**So, every characters which don't output the same term slug at the same level of a taxonomy hierarchy after passed through `sanitize_title()` function are allowed characters.**